# Upper bound for the number of partitions of $n$ into exactly $k$ parts

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

Let $p_k(n)$ the number of partitions of $n$ into exactly $k$ parts.
Do we have $p_k(n) \le 2^{n-k}$ ?

Comment: By subtracting $1$ from each part, $p_k(n)$ is also the number of partitions of $n-k$ into at most $k$ parts. How many partitions of $n-k$ can there be at all?

Answer (score 0):

The number of partitions of a set with $n$ elements into $k$ blocks is given by the Stirling number of the second kind $S(n,k)$. There is an explicit formula and a recursion formula for it.